# Why can't I capture the PayPal transaction in BlueSnap API?

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, bluesnap

I use BlueSnap payment API to do PayPal transactions.

I was told I should do AUTH_ONLY followed by CAPTURE. I did the auth only using the json example in the documentation here:

https://developers.bluesnap.com/v8976-JSON/docs/create-paypal-transaction 
but when I tried to do the second step I got an error message: *Shopping context update service failure. You cannot place a shopping-context with Payment method PayPal*. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The situation you're describing can be caused by trying to go to step 2 of the PayPal flow before the Shopper approved the purchase in PayPal.

The end of step 1 includes a redirect of the shopper to PayPal to finish the purchase, after which the shopper is redirected again to your website. That address to which the shopper is eventually redirected can be configured in the first step as the **returnUrl**, for instance:

```
{
    "amount": 100,
    "softDescriptor": "ABC COMPANY",
    "currency": "USD",
    "paypalTransaction": {
        "cancelUrl": "http://www.cancelURL.com",
        "returnUrl": "http://www.returnURL.com"
    },
    "transactionFraudInfo": {"fraudSessionId": 1234}
}
```

BlueSnap recommends you configure this returnUrl to a receiver address in your website, so you can also get notification when the shopper returns there. When the shopper completed successfully the approval in PayPal, you will be allowed to submit step 2 of the flow.

I hope this helped you.